# Semantic UI Dropdown Search - selecting with the enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working with Semantic UI for a project. I'm using the Search Selection version of the dropdown (classes are 'ui fluid search selection dropdown'). Under each  item, I have setup a custom data-dogs attribute, with either 0 or 1. If the selected item has a data-dogs value of 1, I need an item on my form to show, or hide if it's a 0.

It's working fine on the mouse click, but I'm rather rusty with JS, so I'm not sure if there is an easy way to get the same functionality with the enter key and up/down arrows).

The JS code I've made is below.

If anyone could give me some pointers, I'd very much appreciate it.

Many thanks in advance!

```js
$('.item').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).data('dogs')==1){
            $('#dogCheckbox').removeClass('hidden');
            console.log('Working?');
        } else {
            $('#dogCheckbox').addClass('hidden');
        }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
 <input type="hidden" name="location" id="location_search">
 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
 <div class="default text"></div>
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="item" data-value="1" data-dogs="0">A1</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="2" data-dogs="0">A2</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="3" data-dogs="0">A3</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="4" data-dogs="0">A4</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="5" data-dogs="0">A5</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="6" data-dogs="0">A6</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="7" data-dogs="0">A7</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="8" data-dogs="0">A8</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="9" data-dogs="1">A9</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="10" data-dogs="1">A10</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="11" data-dogs="1">A11</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="12" data-dogs="0">A12</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="13" data-dogs="1">A14</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="14" data-dogs="1">A15</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="15" data-dogs="1">A16</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ui checkbox hidden" id="dogCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" name="
form_dog">
    <label>Dog friendly unit! Is a dog present?</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(".item").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $('.item').click();
    }
});
```

13 is the Enter key code, so- when keyup event occurs, and the pressed key is Enter- do the click function.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Shtut, thanks for that :) I've tried it, but nothing seems to happen. I'm wondering if it's because I'm focused on the <input> tag, rather than the '.item', but I've tried replacing the first ".item" with the input in your example, and it still isn't having it.

Comment: @Allan Wagner I realized that this can be accomplished easily with the use of the 'select' input, and its 'onchange' event.  this is quite different from your original code but you can take a look here and see if it helps- https://jsfiddle.net/16nvz0nk/

Comment: Unfortunately they have specifically asked for this kind of element (having a search bar built into the drop down), because there are several hundred items to go through on the system.